# RegisterPerWebRequest is obsolete, can I use Lifestyle.Scoped?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am just checking for my sanity. This is my code that uses simpleinjector 3.3.2

```
Container.RegisterPerWebRequest<HttpContextBase>(() =>
{
  var context = HttpContext.Current;
  if (context == null && Container.IsVerifying) return new FakeHttpContext();
    return new HttpContextWrapper(context);
});


Container.Verify();
```

...

```
    public class FakeHttpContext : HttpContextBase { }
```

However the RegisterPerWebRequest is now marked as obsolete, I am not 100% sure whether this is the correct way of changing the code to reflect the new code base.

```
Container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();

//So we can inject HttpContextBase into any class
Container.Register<HttpContextBase>( () =>
{
  var context = HttpContext.Current;
  if (context == null && Container.IsVerifying)
    return new FakeHttpContext();

  return new HttpContextWrapper(context);
}, Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

so my question is "Should I use `Lifestyle.Scoped` to replace `RegisterPerWebRequest` and can I still use the code as is?

---

[Judging by the docs I should be doing it right](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetimes.html#per-web-request)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you shown is correct. `Container.Register<T>(Func<T>, Lifestyle.Scoped)` replaces `Container.RegisterPerWebRequest<T>(Func<T>)`.